# Using query params with ReactTable

Tags: reactjs, url, query-string, react-table

I have a react table that looks more or less like this:

```
<ReactTable
          ref={tableRef}
          style={{ minHeight: "80vh" }}
          className="-highlight -striped  text-center"
          data={data}
          loading={isLoading}
          loadingText={getLoadingMessage("Fetching users...")}
          noDataText="No users found..."
          columns={getColumns()}
          filterable={false}
          minRows={0}
          pageSizeOptions={[10, 13, 20, 50, 100]}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          onFetchData={tableState => getUsers({ tableState, searchValue })}
/>
```

I want to use query params so that I can have in my link, depending on the page and rows, something like this ?page=3&rows=50. How can I implement this using hooks?

This is how getUsers looks like:

```
getUsers: thunk(async (actions, { tableState, searchValue }) => {
    actions.setIsLoading(true);

    let QUERIES = getQueryParamsFromTable(tableState, searchValue);

    try {
      const { data } = await api.get(urlParamReplacer(AUTH.USERS), {
        params: QUERIES
      });
      actions.setUsers(data);
    } catch (error) {
      actions.setIsLoading(false);
      console.error(error);
    }
  }),
```

and this is setIsLoading:

```
setIsLoading: action((state, payload) => {
    state.isLoading = payload;
  }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom hook to return the query parameters or implement the [use-query-params](https://github.com/pbeshai/use-query-params) library.

With the use-query-params library, it can be implemented with the following code:

```
const [query, setQuery] = useQueryParams({
  page: NumberParam,
  rows: NumberParam,
});
const [page, setPage] = useState(query.page || 0);

<ReactTable
  ref={tableRef}
  style={{ minHeight: "80vh" }}
  className="-highlight -striped  text-center"
  data={data}
  loading={isLoading}
  loadingText={getLoadingMessage("Fetching users...")}
  noDataText="No users found..."
  columns={getColumns()}
  filterable={false}
  minRows={0}
  pageSizeOptions={[10, 13, 20, 50, 100]}
  defaultPageSize={10}
  page={page}
  pageSize={query.rows}
  onPageChange={pageIndex => setPage(pageIndex)}
  onFetchData={tableState => getUsers({ tableState, searchValue })}
/>
```

Here is an example with a custom hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const usePagination = (initialPage = 0, initialRows = 50) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  const history = useHistory();

  const [page, updatePage] = useState(Number(searchParams.get("page")) || initialPage);
  const [rows, updateRows] = useState(Number(searchParams.get("rows")) || initialRows);

  useEffect(() => {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    
    updatePage(Number(searchParams.get('page')) || page);
    updateRows(Number(searchParams.get('rows')) || rows);
  }, [location, page, rows]);

  const setPage = toPage => {
    searchParams.set("page", toPage || initialPage);
    history.push({ search: searchParams.toString() });
  };

  const setRows = toRows => {
    searchParams.set("rows", toRows || initialRows);
    history.push({ search: searchParams.toString() });
  };

  return {
    page,
    rows,
    setPage,
    setRows
  };
};

export default usePagination;
```

```
const { page, rows, setPage, setRows } = usePagination();

<ReactTable
  ref={tableRef}
  style={{ minHeight: "80vh" }}
  className="-highlight -striped  text-center"
  data={data}
  loading={isLoading}
  loadingText={getLoadingMessage("Fetching users...")}
  noDataText="No users found..."
  columns={getColumns()}
  filterable={false}
  minRows={0}
  pageSizeOptions={[10, 13, 20, 50, 100]}
  defaultPageSize={10}
  page={page}
  pageSize={rows}
  onPageChange={pageIndex => setPage(pageIndex)}
  onPageSizeChange={(pageSize, pageIndex) => {
    setPage(pageIndex);
    setRows(pageSize);
  }}
  onFetchData={tableState => getUsers({ tableState, searchValue })}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to almost work (I used the second option) but I have two issues: whenever I try to search for a specifc url, the data is loaded in the back but the page appears as if it is still loading for some reason ("fetching users..." appears as an overlay). Do you have any idea why this might happen? Also how can I implement the back functionality? The url is updated whenever I press back but the page does not reload.

Comment: The first problem sounds like an issue with your `getUsers` and `isLoading` logic. I have to see more of your code in order to help you with that. Regarding your second problem, are you using react-router? If so, I can update the answer which solves that problem.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the two blocks of code for the first problem. I am not sure this is where the problem lies though and I don't know if you can help me just with that. I have just noticed that behind the overlay the page counter seems to somehow concatenate with the page query parameter. Whenever  I have ?page=3 for example I get 31. The data loads correctly but it gets stuck on loading.. probably because of that. And yes, I am using react-router. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you also set `actions.setIsLoading(false);` when the request successfully stored the data? E.g. after `actions.setUsers(data);`

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't seem to work... I'll try to work it out myself. But if you can help me with the second issue I will be very grateful.

Comment: Updated the answer with the react-router version. Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-usesearchparams-7b2ne?file=/src/usePagination.js)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This apparently also fixed the constant loading problem.